# Adding Motion artifact noise in Mat lab

Tags: matlab, noise

I want to add motion artifact noise in a magnetic resonance images images using Mat lab. please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question and after going through Mat Lab documentation I get the answer.
https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html

```
     I = (imread("1.png"));
     Patch_size = 512;
     imshow(I);
     title("Original image");

     image is created now add motion to that image and then blur it

     % motion noise

     H = fspecial('motion');
     MotionBlur = imfilter(I,H,'replicate');
     imshow(MotionBlur);
     title('Motion Noise')
```